# Метод getSelectedItem выводит item который стоит по умолчанию а по идее должен выводить item который ставиться в spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

```
    private fun getSpinnerData(): String {
        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCurrency)

        when(spinner.selectedItem.toString()) {
            "Рубль" -> {
                return "₽"
            }

            "Доллар" -> {
                return "$"
            }

            "Евро" -> {
                return "€"
            }

            "Тенге"-> {
                return "₸"
            }
        }

        return getSpinnerData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать слушатель onItemSelectedListener чтобы получать изменения при выборе элементов в spinner примерно следующим образом:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.yourSpinner) as Spinner
var selectedText = textList.first() // элемент по умолчанию

if (spinner != null) {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, textList )
    spinner.adapter = adapter

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
      override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            selectedText = textList[position]
      }

     override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

     }
 }
```

}

Изменения будут сохраняться в переменную selectedText.